# Using new again on the same object in C#

Tags: c#, new-operator

```
namespace usenewagain
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Thread thread1;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            thread1 = new Thread(() => threadsDelegate(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), 1) );
            thread1.Start();

            while(thread1.IsAlive)
            {

            }

            thread1 = new Thread(() => threadsDelegate(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), 1));
            thread1.Start();

            while(thread1.IsAlive)
            {

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell in this console program using new on thread1 again is legal and it appears it works fine. As far as I can tell the thread1 is overwritten with the second call to new. Could I get some verification that using new again is valid this way?

Thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.

every time you use `new`, you are creating a new object, and storing a **reference** to that object in your variable.

So

```
thread1 = new Thread(...)
```

makes a new instance of `Thread` and stores a reference to that instance in `thread1`.

---

when you do it a second time, you are making an second instance of `Thread`, but you are not destroying the old one.  You are just overwriting the **reference**, which is  just the "address" of the thread.

however, you do have the garbage collector, which will clean up the first thread if you have no references to it, so if somewhere, a reference to your first remains, (like if you assigned it to some other variable), it will not get garbage collected.

Comment: So perhaps running GC.Collect may help then?

Comment: @user2209542 no, it won't help.  Even if you run GC.Collect, if there's still a reference to the thread, it won't be collected.  I personally like to avoid manual garbage collection and let the garbage collector do it's thing.

Comment: So there is no other reference only thread1 so then you must be saying there isn't a problem and thread1 will be garbage collected in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If by "Valid" you mean "Will Compile" and "Will overwrite my variable" then yes, it is valid.

It is however, dangerous. By overwriting the variable, you lose any reference to it if you want to perform a `Join` or any other operation on it. If you wait for the thread to `Join`, which by the way is preferred to your spin wait, it is a safe operation.

Comment: *spin-wait. A spin lock is something different.

Comment: @dcastro, excellent point. A spin lock is used to avoid race conditions. A spin wait just wastes CPU cycles waiting for something else to finish.